# CustomSeekBar with fading alpha color gradient, black thin border, and tiled background

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

## The goal

I'm trying to replicate this Dialog.

[image: TheDialog]

## The current state

But I've only gotten to this point (showing only the relevant part):

[image: MyDialog]

## What is missing

A way to add a thin black border surrounding my custom Seekbar's "progress area", and a tiled background restricted to that "progress area".

## My code

As it is, my `CustomSeekBar` (which `extends AppCompatSeekBar`) works fine for setting a starting and ending color in the code. Here is the function:

```
public void setGradientColor(@ColorInt int leftColor, @ColorInt int rightcolor) {
    grad = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[] {leftColor, rightcolor});
    setProgressDrawable(grad);
}
```

But trying to set the background's image ends up looking like my very last seekbar in the `The current state` image (the background extends outside of the progress area and fills all of the view's area):

```
    aSeekBar.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.checker));
    aSeekBar.setGradientColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"), Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
```

My `checker.xml` file in `res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/checkerstile"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    />
```

Comment: Why don't you make your seekbar background transparent and put a Layout with what you want behind the seekbar? won't be it easier?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you are suggesting to modify my dialog's layout xml to add layout layers, I am not allowed to do that. I would also need that colors specified to start and end right at the progress are, and not the view itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a viable solution:

```
    int padding = aSeekBar.getPaddingStart();
    InsetDrawable bgImg = new InsetDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.checker), padding);
    aSeekBar.setBackground(bgImg);
```

Combine this with [the solution from Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269026/9768291) for the border and you get this result:

[image: phone_demo]

Answer (score 1):

For the "Border" part of your question, you just have to add a Stroke to your GradientDrawable :

```
  public void setGradientColor(@ColorInt int leftColor, @ColorInt int rightcolor) {
        grad = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[] {leftColor, rightcolor});
        grad.setStroke(/* stroke width*/, /* int color*/);
        setProgressDrawable(grad);
    }
```

For that, it that easy, sorry i can't help for the background.

Comment: This worked. I had tried `.setStroke()` before, but I guess I must've been placing it at the wrong place and it would get overwritten.